# What is the relation between two row equivalent matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is very simple.

Suppose $[T]_{\mathfrak B}$ is the matrix of the linear transformation $T:V\to V$ in the basis $\mathfrak B$.

> If a matrix $A$ is [row equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_equivalence) to $[T]_{\mathfrak B}$, what is the relation between these two matrices?

Can we know something about the linear transformation $T$ just looking to the matrix $A$?

Comment: "If a matrix $A$ is row equivalent to $[T]_B$, what is the relation between these two matrices?" Doesn't the question answer itself? What "relation are you looking for?

Comment: @Jack  Can we know something about the linear transformation $T$ just looking to the matrix $A$?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we know something about the linear transformation $T$ just looking to the matrix $A$?

Yes, we can. For instance, the rank of $A$ is equal to that of $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$, which would give you the information about where $T$ is invertible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Note that **Elementary row operation of a matrix $A$ means multiplication of $A$ by an elementary matrix from the left**.

A matrix $E$ is called **elementary** if it can be obtained from the identity matrix $I$ by a single row operation.

Since $B$ is obtained from $A$ by elementary row operations so $B$ will have the form $B=PA$ where $P=E_kE_{k-1}\ldots E_1$ where $E_i$ denotes an elementary row operation and

$k=$Number of operations needed to obtain $B$ from $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using your reasoning is it possible to say something about $T$ knowing that $A=P[T]_{\mathfrak B}$?

Comment: Yes you can know everything about $T$ looking at $A$ because the first column of $A$ is the image of the first basis vector under $T$ and so on..

Comment: did you mean the matrix $[T]_{\mathfrak B}$?

Comment: Yes I meant that